# Authenticating against the Yammer JS SDK using ADAL in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, yammer

After scouring the internet, I've found a variety of answers to this question, but nothing is clear. With an Azure AD app, it looks like Yammer Delegate permissions are included so I would imagine that I could use then ADAL token from the app, to interact with Yammer APIs but have been running into issues. Has anyone else got this working? Is there any way to silently authenticate with yammer in SharePoint online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yammer Delegate permissions are a preview feature. Long-term we plan to integrate fully with the O365 developer experience, but aren't quite there yet. Today, Yammer supports a number of scenarios that don't align with O365. Once the product better aligns it's going to be possible to provide much deeper integration (not just limited to developer APIs.) One limitation of the delegate permission is that it won't work with networks that are using Yammer Identity. Another is that some endpoints might not accept the tokens.

The supported authentication flows for Yammer are [documented](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2) on the developer site and these support users with all authentication types for Yammer. With these APIs you'll end up juggling an additional Yammer-only token. It is possible to use [impersonation](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/impersonation) to silently authenticate users without them being prompted to authorize the Yammer app. There is a [blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askyammer/2016/11/04/preauthorizing-the-yammer-js-sdk/) providing an overview of how this can be used in combination with the Yammer JS SDK, but the tokens could be used from other clients.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Brian Lyttle!